# Query returning UTC timezone although using AT TIME ZONE

Tags: postgresql

I have data in GMT timezone. I want to convert and display them in `'America/New_York'`.

This is the code I use:

```
(d.start_time) AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York'
```

It returns let's say `2021-10-25T09:30:00.000Z`.

9:30 is the correct time. But why is it a UTC time zone timestamp instead of `'America/New_York'`?

I tried various variations of `with/without time zone` and `::timestamp`/`::timestamptz` but I probably doesn't understand something very basic in here...

What should I do differently so that it's valid 9:30am timestamp in `'America/New_York'` timezone?

Comment: What is the type for `d.start_time`? What does `d.start_time` return without the time zone conversion? What is `TimeZone` set to(`SHOW TimeZone`)?

Comment: PostgreSQL does not put a 'Z' there.  Either you are using a non-standard variant of PostgreSQL, or your connection library is doing you a disservice.

Comment: @jjanes I see. My "tooling" is really a bit non standard. But I have to work with it. I can still parse it to whatever format I want as a string. What should a proper Postgres timestamp string look like then?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver d.start_time without time zone conversion return exactly the same format, just a different time. I have UTC timezone set. But it seems I cannot change it in my tooling.

Comment: This seems to be a client issue with `Retool`.  As  @jjanes, mentioned the timestamp format you show is not coming from Postgres.  Are you using the `date time picker` component? If so you might want to look here [Date time picker](https://retool.com/components#DateTimePicker) and see what `useLocalTimezone` is set to.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Even worse - I'm using Calendar component. It doesn't seem to have a similar option. Retool doesn't implement most of the original FullCalendar implementation.

Comment: So you are running into `Without a Plugin ("UTC-coercion")` from here [timeZone](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/timeZone). This is not a Postgres issue but a FullCalendar/Javascript one.

Answer (score 1):

The result is correct: 2021-10-25T09:30:00.000 is a `timestamp without time zone`, and it is *not* a UTC timestamp, but local time in New York City.

If you want the timestamp to be displayed with the time zone offset of New York City, you have to do something different:

```
SET timezone = 'America/New_York';
SELECT current_timestamp;

       current_timestamp       
═══════════════════════════════
 2021-10-11 12:45:49.881037-04
(1 row)
```

Then PostgreSQL will display `timestamp with time zone` values with the offset you want.

Comment: I see, thanks. Is it possible that `SET timezone = 'America/New_York'; SELECT ...` returns syntax error near "SET"? I'm using a bit weird setup (retool + read only database connection). Not sure if that's relevant.

Comment: That should work; perhaps your client has a problem with that. You can also use `SET LOCAL` to change the parameter only for the current database transaction.

Comment: Is there a way do achieve what I want without setting timezone? It seems the Retool client behaves very weirdly about this and it's my constraint to use it.

Comment: I mean something like this `to_char(e.start, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS".000-04:00"') as start,`. I'm just not sure how it will behave in the browsers of the end users.

Comment: Just use your query and append the offset yourself. It should be predictable.